# Uncrustify options indent_ctor_init and indent_ctor_init_leading seems not to work

Tags: c++, code-formatting, uncrustify

I want to intend the constructor initializer list using:

> Virtual indent from the ':' for member initializers. Default is 2
>
> indent_ctor_init_leading                  = 2
>
> Additional indenting for constructor initializer list
>
> indent_ctor_init                          = 2

No meter what I set to this 2 options, the initialization list remain in the same position.

I'm using Uncrustify 0.63.

This is what I get:

```
one_class::one_class(
 const std::string& name,
 i_event_processing_callback* const event_processing_callback ):
 inherited_class( name, event_processing_callback ),
 status( t_status::NEW ),
 run_and_event_mutex(),
 run_and_event_condition(),
 worker_thread(),
 m_run( false ) 
{
    // Nothing to do...
}
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
one_class::one_class(
 const std::string& name,
 i_event_processing_callback* const event_processing_callback ):
  inherited_class( name, event_processing_callback ),
  status( t_status::NEW ),
  run_and_event_mutex(),
  run_and_event_condition(),
  worker_thread(),
  m_run( false )    
{
    // Nothing to do...
}
```

Am I doing something wrong or how can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

A issue is opened on github at https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify/issues/146

Comment: `one_class:one_class` looks like colon is missed `:` => `::`.

Comment: Yep, my mistake. But the question remains.